# Python: add a timestamp to each object in the list

Tags: python, python-2.7, collections

I have a collection of objects, and I would like to add a timestamp to each of them:

```
t = time.utcnow()  
for x in objects:
    x['created_at'] = t
```

Is there a way to do this inline?

Comment: You want a 1 liner solution?

Comment: You want to add the same time stamp to all? at once (in one go)?

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil, Yes, that's what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly pretty (assuming `x` is a dictionary):

```
t = time.utcnow()
map(lambda x: x.update({'created_at': t}), objects)
```

Comment: `update` returns `None`. On this reason we will get a list of `None`

Comment: Assign the mapping to `objects` then?

Comment: @Antonio the `map()` returns a list of `None` objects but the original `objects` list will have updated dictionaries.